# Can someone explain to me why the console outputs 0?

Tags: c++

This was a question on my intro to programming mid term and I don't understand why the answer is not 2.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 10;

if( x != y )
{
    int x = 2;
}
else
{
    x++;
}

cout << x;
```

Comment: `int x = 2;` **!=** `x = 2;`

Comment: Read up on a) scopes, b) shadowing variables.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you, I just needed to be pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you're shadowing (creating a new variable) your `x` inside the `if` statement.  If you remove `int` before the `x` inside the `if`, `x` will be 2 when you print it.

Comment: In C++, `{}`'s create a new scope. Inside that new scope, the code creates an integer called `x` and sets its value to 2. But after the `}`, that variable goes out of scope and ceases to exist.

Comment: Re: "it'll work" -- work, as in do something different. Be careful about making assumptions about what code is **supposed** to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update to be more clear.

Comment: But he didn't write the code; this is an exam question, and the question is why does it do what it does. Good clarification!

Comment: Good point, i'll update my previous comment as I now see it was erroneous.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh you're right, thanks!  Is that exclusive to C++?

Comment: @MichaelLeonard not *exclusive* to C++. It's the same in C and other languages (but not *all*). You always need to know the rules of the language you are using and you can never assume that what's a rule/syntax/idiom in one language is the same in another. All programming languages are different (sometimes *subtly* so) and each one needs to be learned individually.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable x twice in two different areas. Remove the int before the x in the loop and you should be good to go. You could do x = x+2 or x+=2 to add two to the variable.

Comment: No. The question is not "how can I make this code do something different", it's **why does it do what it does?**. The first sentence is correct. The rest is guessing at what someone might have meant this code to do, and since this is an exam question, any guess other than "illustrate how local scopes work" is almost certainly wrong.